# JQuery load content from a remote site

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, tumblr

I would like to load content from another site using JQuery,
Unfortunately the .load() function is limited to the current domain.
Is there any way around ? I would like to insert à navigation bar directly into a tumblr blog.

Comment: oddly, sites disallow ajax loading of content from "other sites" but do allow javascript loading from other sites with the same "http vs. https" ness FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
If you have control over the other side it is quite easy. Otherwise try [Yahoos YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at cross domain ajax request with `YQL` and `jQuery`.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/