# Iframe a div from a website

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Searched for this thing and tried all of them but i can't seem to make it work.

I want to iframe only a specific part of the website into a forum post, the forum supports html posting.
I want to iframe the div: ptContainer from this website doodle.com/5bd7fzirdd3gnbzh to a post here interncup-thc.ucoz.com/forum/5-1-2
The post which seems to be empty actually has this code inside:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script> $("#ptContainer").load("http://doodle.com/5bd7fzirdd3gnbzh");</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With that code you are not framing, your are loading. There is a big difference between the two actions.

### Iframe:

> The HTML  Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a
>   nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into
>   the current page. Each browsing context has its own session history
>   and active document. The browsing context that contains the embedded
>   content is called the parent browsing context. The top-level browsing
>   context (which has no parent) is typically the browser window.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

### jQuery load:

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/

The two solution are not related; is important to know what you want to do.

If you want to use iframe you can do a simple html iframe like:

```
<iframe src="http://doodle.com/5bd7fzirdd3gnbzh" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/32bDj/

With the use of iframes you have no direct/simple control to the content of the iframed page.

With jQuery load the problem is that you facing is a not allowed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` a typical Cross Domain request issue.
Check here the solutions: [JQuery load content from a remote site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973672/jquery-load-content-from-a-remote-site)

Comment: what i actually want is a way to get that schedule table into my forum with any necessary means. only the table content and nothing else, but i can't seem to find any way to do it

Comment: Scrap html from other pages is not usually a good idea; considering that you don't have control of the scraped website you must check out JQL, get the page using it, scrap the resulting page, and extract the div "#pollContainer" (always hoping that doodle not change the rendered HTML )

Comment: already checked jquery load and couldn't make it work, that's why i'm asking help, i just can't seem to get only the "#ptContainer" on my forum

Comment: You CANNOT use jquery load because of Cross Domain Request, try using JQL, read the answer first.