# PHP - How to include a section of a site?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to include a section of one html document (X) in another one (Y).

There's:

```
<div id="cmform">
....
....
</div>
```

in html document X and I need to include it in a div in html document Y. I started to read PHP documentation and have found an info about "file_get_contents" function. If I do:

```
<?php
   $a = file_get_contents("http://site.com/document.html");
   echo ($a);
?>
```

I get the whole page and I don't know how to... narrow it to that one div...

Comment: do you know what the xpath of the div is?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what xpath is.

Comment: what is the url and form that you are trying to fetch?

Comment: It's on a local server so any url will do in an example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOMDocument class in PHP.

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Example:

```
$documentText = file_get_contents("http://site.com/document.html");
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML( $documentText );
$myDivNode = $domDocument->getElementById( 'the-id-of-the-div' );
$myDivText = $domDocument->saveHTML( $myDivNode );
echo $myDivText;
```

Comment: I get an error: Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /public_html/test/form.php on line 53

Comment: The parameter in that method was added in PHP 5.3.6, I just read.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it:

1. If the remote site has CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *), you can inject it using an AJAX request; Please note that this will fail on browsers that do not support CORS
2. You can parse it on the server

Option 2 is by far your preferred approach and relies on two libraries (three if you're like me): **curl**, which will handle the HTTP request, and **DOMDocument**, which handles the parsing.

I wrote a parser for someone a while back. You can find it there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144603/2167834 . It has a lot of detailed explanations on how to go through the DOM using `DOMDocument`.

Please note that `DOMDocument` is especially prone to breaking on the following:

1. Incorrect charset definitions
2. Broken HTML
3. Inline JavaScript

You can, however, rewrite your source to deal with this.

In your case, once you have the DOMDocument and DOMXPath object, you want to `query("//[@id=\"cmform\"]")`. The two forward slashes mean "any parent", [@id is an exact match on the parameter id.

Note that **this will fail if the DOM document has multiple elements with the same ID. They shouldn't have, by HTML spec.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns an string representig the content of the file, the simplest way you have is to parse the string to get the value of the div, check this example:

```
$html = 'hola <div id="cmform">'.
            "the content of div".
            "</div>adios";

echo preg_replace('/(.+)<div id="cmform">(.+)<\/div>(.+)/m', '\2', $html);
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use something like .load function in jquery

Comment: `$('#cmform').load('document.html #div_id');`

Comment: There's a complicated, dynamic form that I want to include and I already have had a lot of troubles using jquery to handle it.

Comment: @Maria u mean dynamically created form or dynamically what?

Comment: It's a form generated by Gravity Form WP plugin with a lot of fields and complex logic conditions.

Comment: Do you know form url(dynamic form generate path) ?

Comment: It's a local server running WP.

Comment: if you can create a widget for that form u can load it for another place

Comment: The other site is not a part of Wordpress.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973672/jquery-load-content-from-a-remote-site

Comment: load the requested url in an iframe rather than a div by setting the src parameter using JS. Simple, easy but would limit your access to the data in the iframe.

Comment: No it is not that simple. The form shows extra fields depending on multiple chooses so the iframe height changes. It doesn't look good.

Comment: Do u think u can't use iframe because of what extractly ?